# loading tocloft makes \ifdefined\chapter TRUE in article class

Tags: sectioning, chapters, tocloft

I am using the `article` class, and I discovered that the `tocloft` package defines `\chapter`, which will mess up with my other stuff. How does this happen? Can I make `\chapter` "undefined" again after loading `tocloft`? Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
% loading tocloft will make \chapter defined
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}

\ifdefined\chapter
   chapter is defined in the current \texttt{article} document.

   \chapter{This is not a chapter, but will be typeset as plain text}
\else
   chapter is \emph{not} defined.
\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting... If you do not require the usual definition of `\chapter` then redefining it should be fine.

Answer (score 16):

Some packages and macros check whether `\chapter` is defined or not in order to take some action; for example, to typeset the bibliography as a chapter (`book` and `report` classes) or as a section (`article` class).

The test they perform is based on `\@ifundefined`, something like

```
\@ifundefined{chapter}
  {\section*{\refname}}
  {\chapter*{\bibname}}
```

It's important to know that `\@ifundefined` returns true when the command given in the argument by its name is undefined or equivalent to `\relax`. Actually, whenever one uses

```
\@ifundefined{foo}{<true>}{<false>}
```

the command `\foo` will become equivalent to `\relax` if it weren't defined before.

Conversely, the `\ifdefined` conditional returns true also when the token after it is equivalent to `\relax` and this is why you observe this behavior: indeed `tocloft` checks for the existence of `\chapter` with `\@ifundefined`.

The reason for this is historical: LaTeX needs to know whether `\foo` is defined or not when `\newenvironment{foo}` is issued, or `\c@foo` for `\newcounter{foo}`. So the macro `\@ifundefined` takes as argument the name, rather than the token itself. It uses internally `\csname...\endcsname` which has the effect outlined before: if `\foo` is undefined, then using `\csname foo\encsname` will let it to be equivalent to `\relax`.

There should be no problem as long as you stick to `\@ifundefined` to test for definedness.

The `\ifdefined` and `\ifcsname` primitives are e-TeX extensions, so they were not available when LaTeX2e was released. There was really no other reliable way to check for definedness; a different strategy would have been to compare with an undefined token (there is `\@undefined` for this). However, the `\csname...\endcsname` problem would remain, unless one uses a slick trick:

```
\def\@ifundefined#1{%
    \begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
    \expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\@undefined
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi}
```

so that `\@ifundefined{foo}` wouldn't leave `\foo` equivalent to `\relax` if it wasn't defined. However this test is not completely expandable because of `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`, so the developers decided to leave `\@ifundefined` as it was.

The trick works because `\csname foo\endcsname` is performed before TeX scans the `\endgroup` and so the equivalence with `\relax` vanishes as soon as TeX executes it; but the conditional `\ifx` has already been expanded. :)

---

Note that in LaTeX releases from 2018 onwards the definition of `\@ifundefined` has been modified so that it no longer defines the tested command to be `\relax` if it was previously undefined.

Comment: Great explanation!

Comment: So now, all those documents that relied on having `\@ifundefined` return `\relax` will crash? Assuming one upgrades to 2018, that is. Don't feel bad. In the early days of JavaScript, one might have to use `var undefined=undefined` or otherwise, `undefined` was undefined.

Comment: @RobtAll I don't think this is a problem: `\@ifundefined{foo}` followed one branch or another according to the status of `\foo`. It doesn't “return `\relax`”.

Answer (score 8):

[`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) defines `\chapter` as `\relax` in `article`. If you want it undefined, issue

```
\usepackage{tocloft}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft
\let\chapter\undefined
```

Here `\undefined` is merely an undefined control sequence. It might just as well have been `\anyundefinedmacro`, just as long as it is *also* undefined.

`\let` copies the entire definition of the second control sequence into the first as it is defined at that moment. Since `\undefined` does not exist, `\chapter` will "not exist." Depending on your other usages, you may have to remove other `\chapter`-related definitions as well. However, without more information, this should suffice.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% loading tocloft will make \chapter defined
\usepackage{tocloft}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft
\let\chapter\undefined
\begin{document}

\ifdefined\chapter
   chapter is defined in the current \texttt{article} document.

   \chapter{This is not a chapter, but will be typeset as plain text}
\else
   chapter is \emph{not} defined.
\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Werner and @egreg, great explanation and example!

Comment: Just add another observation: issuing `\pagestyle{fancy}` (by package [fancyhdr](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr)) also makes `\chapter` defined, but `\pagestyle{plain}` or merely loading the package does not. I found this out by peeling off my lengthy preambles with `\let\chapter\undefined`. Thanks again!